# TensorFlow: Where is the actual implementation of RMSprop?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, gradient-descent

In "rmsprop.py" (in TensorFlow) there is a call to the method *apply_rms_prop*. This method is defined in "gen_training_ops.py". In the definition of this method there is a comment describing what it is supposed to do:

```
ms <- rho * ms_{t-1} + (1-rho) * grad * grad
mom <- momentum * mom_{t-1} + lr * grad / sqrt(ms + epsilon)
var <- var - mom
```

But I can't seem to find where the actual python implementation of the pseudo code above is. My guess is that it is implemented in cpython since I was able to find the file "__pycache__/rmsprop.cpython-36.pyc". But again, where is the cpython implementation that performs the pseudo code above?

My goal is to implement my own gradient update methods, so I need to see some concrete implementation examples (e.g. rmsprop, adam, etc.). Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement your own optimizer from the [`Optimizer`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py) class. You have to implement at least one of the method `_apply_dense` or `_apply_sparse`.

A complete implementation of [`adamax`](https://github.com/openai/iaf/blob/master/tf_utils/adamax.py) optimizer using pure already available tensorflow ops.

```
class AdamaxOptimizer(optimizer.Optimizer):
..
   you can create slot variables implementing slot fucntion
   def _create_slots(self, var_list):
       ...
   def _apply_dense(self, grad, var):
        implement your logic for gradient updates here.
```

Answer (score 3):

You can find the implementations under [`tensorflow/core/kernels`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/). The CPU version is in [`training_ops.cc`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/training_ops.cc) and the GPU (CUDA) version in [`training_ops_gpu.cu.cc`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/training_ops_gpu.cu.cc) (look for the template struct `ApplyRMSProp`). Other optimizer update rule implementations can also be found in those files.

I *think* the CPython code is automatically generated using the kernel registration macros at the end of the file, grouping the different implementations under one op name (translated from camel case to snake case in Python) that you use independently of the device.